# Yosemite white-screen crash (with avatar)

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, macos, crash

Recently upgraded to OSX 10.10 on a Mid 2012 MBP (13 inch) - no problem encountered.  But a few times now I've experienced a white-screen crash.  When waking from sleep the system just shows a white screen with the round user avatar picture in the middle.  Nothing I do can bring up the proper login screen except a hard reset. 
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: No solution, but additional details. I have the same problem, when returning from sleep instead of a quick return to the desktop I get the white/gray screen with user login. When you provide login credentials the it will boot from disk image (you get the gray progress bar, takes 10-20 seconds) and then restore apps. The MS Office apps (e.g. Excel) all restore with a popup notice that files were saved when Excel quit unexpectedly. This confirms that the system is not behaving normally. It appears that safe sleep is failing somewhere and OS X is restoring from the hibernated disk image rather th

Comment: FWIW this happens to me too on a mac mini; typing in my password works. Not using photo-based screensaver. Very annoying.

Comment: Closed @daniel-lawson?  It's a new problem regarding a new OS - how can you possibly know enough about it to decreeing it 'too broad'?  Of course if you do please enlighten us.

Comment: Asking "has anyone else experienced this" has literally as many correct answers as there readers of the question. If you are asking for a fix, that's a great question, but asking simply for others to confirm that they have or have not encountered the problem is far too broad a question.

Comment: I think you're applying a rule-of-thumb inappropriately.  The problem has no obvious cause, just a clear context, so of course it's a bit vague.  Sometimes pinning these nebulous problems down means getting an SO question published so people can come together to share experiences, which is hindered by over-zealous moderation.  If this is a redundant duplicate no problem otherwise please reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have experienced this - if you type in your password and press enter, it will 'unlock'. I think it's a glitch.

Comment: Great, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.
I have to hard reboot the mac

What i have found is it might be the new Photos Based screensaver which could be causing this.

So I have disabled that and now monitoring if i can run into this issue again!

Typically for me the issue reproduces consistently in the following steps:

1) Let the Mac run on battery
2) Drain the power completely
3) plug in the power cable and boot it back up

bizarreeeee..... its stuck at the white screen with avatar on it and no place for inputting the password!!!!

Comment: Did you try just typing the password and enter?